# I cannot submit any data to the console in my Vue project

Tags: forms, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am trying to test a form in Vue, using the forms from the Bootstrap-Vue library.
I have made a an event for the form (submit) and I added a function to this event (addText).
Then I made a method for this function, telling it to log my input data to the console, but when I press the "save" button and go into the console nothing has been logged.

This used to work with Materialize, so I am wondering if the error lies somewhere with the Bootstrap forms.

Any help will be much appreciated.

```
 <template>
<b-container fluid>
    <h2>Add or edit content for this section</h2>
      <b-form-group @submit="addText">
          <div class="fieldHeadline">
              <label for="headline">Add headline</label>
              <b-form-input type="text" name="headline" v-model="headline"></b-form-input>
          </div>
          <div class="fieldSecodnaryHeadline">
              <label for="secondaryHeadline">Add secondary headline</label>
              <b-form-input type="text" name="secondaryHeadline" v-model="secondaryHeadline"></b-form-input>
          </div>
          <div class="fieldText">
              <label for="text">add text</label>
              <b-form-input type="text" name="text" v-model="text"></b-form-input>
          </div>
          <b-button variant="success">Save</b-button>
      </b-form-group>
</b-container>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: 'NewsSectionCreate',
    data() {
        return {
            headline: null,
            secondaryHeadline: null,
            text: null
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addText(){
            console.log(this.headline, this.secondaryHeadline, this.text)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I think the @submit event does not exists on `b-form-group`, need to be on `b-form`: https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form, https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-group

Answer (score 1):

`b-form-group` is not a form it's layout that structures the label and inputs, in order to submit that inputs you should wrap the `b-form-group` tags with a `b-form` component which has `@submit` event:

```
 <b-form @submit="addText">
  <b-form-group >
      <div class="fieldHeadline">
          <label for="headline">Add headline</label>
          <b-form-input type="text" name="headline" v-model="headline"></b-form-input>
      </div>
      <div class="fieldSecodnaryHeadline">
          <label for="secondaryHeadline">Add secondary headline</label>
          <b-form-input type="text" name="secondaryHeadline" v-model="secondaryHeadline"></b-form-input>
      </div>
      <div class="fieldText">
          <label for="text">add text</label>
          <b-form-input type="text" name="text" v-model="text"></b-form-input>
      </div>
      <b-button type="submit" variant="success">Save</b-button>
  </b-form-group>
 </b-form->
```

don't forget to add `type="submit"` to the `b-button` component.

Comment: You're welcome, please don't forget to accept my answer